# Issue With jQuery Slider - Wont Close Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**http://jsfiddle.net/waJzP/43/**

I'll break down the issues with functionality -

1. If you click Open (stage 1), then click open more (stage 2), then click Close - Open more (stage 2) stays open. But if you click Open More (stage 2), and then click open more (stage 3) and then click close - they all close properly. Why is this?
2. "Open Pictures" does not close properly. Also, if you have "open more (stage 2)" and "open more (stage 3)" open, they should close when you click on open pictures. But it doesnt!

I'm so new to jquery, this is all very confusing!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.stage1').hide();  
    $("#stage1").click(function () {
      $(".stage1").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });
    $('.stage2').hide();  
      $("#stage2").click(function () {
        $(".stage2").slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      $('.stage3').hide();  
      $("#stage3").click(function () {
        $(".stage3").slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    $('.photos').hide();  
      $("#photos").click(function () {
        $(".photos").slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
         $("#showmap").click(function () {
          if ($('.stage2, .stage3').is(':hidden'))
             {$(".stage1").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000); }
             else
             {
              $(".stage3").slideToggle();
              $(".stage2").slideToggle();
              $(".stage1").delay(1000).toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
             }
        });
});
```

----------------------------- HTML -----------------------------

```
<div id="stage1">Open</div>      
<div id="showmap">close (closes all)</div>
<div class="map-wrapper">

<img src="http://placehold.it/1000x300" width="100%">
<div class="stage1 map-main-slider">   <br>
<div id="stage2">open more</div>
<div id="photos"> Open Pictures (Should close stages 2 and 3 if open) </div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div class="photos" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
<div> <br> <br> <br> I am Photos <br> <br> <br>  </div>
</div>
<div class="stage2" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
<div id="stage3"> <br> <br> <br> Open More <br> <br> <br>  </div>
<div class="stage3" style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;text-align:center;"><br> <br> <br>I am More Infmation <br> <br> <br> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

--------------------------------- CSS

```
.map-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

.map-main-slider {
    background-color: rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.96);
    background-image: url("/wordpress/wp-content/themes/penrose/img/noise.png");
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.map-inner {
  padding:4%
}

.stage2{
background:blue;

}

.stage3{
background:red;

}
.photos {background:green;}
```

Comment: For one thing, `e.preventDefault()` is not being used properly, nor does it look like it's even needed here.

Comment: When I didn't have it - the toggle would not function properly (it wasnt smooth, it glitched)

Comment: You have `id` `#stage1` and `class` `.stage1`.  Technically, nothing wrong, but having the same name used for two different things is potentially confusing.

Comment: It's throwing an error @AnthonyA. Check your console.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` can't have anything to do with your glitch.... it's not even being used here because of programming error.  See console.

Comment: Yea, I just checked the console - ok I'll get rid of it

Comment: Also, please also include your HTML in the question.  The jsFiddle link will not last forever.

Comment: Ok, I added the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

In Showmap click function check initial if check was not correct. I have modified as below code

```
$("#showmap").click(function () {
      if ($('.stage2').is(':hidden') && $('.stage3').is(':hidden'))
         {
             $(".stage1").toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000); }
         else
         {
          $(".stage3").slideToggle();
          $(".stage2").slideToggle();
          $(".stage1").delay(1000).toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
         }
    });
```

Please the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/waJzP/45/
thanks

Comment: If the OP wants "close all" to close everything, [that's not working](http://jsfiddle.net/waJzP/45/).

Comment: Yea, It needs to close everything thats open in order

Comment: hi Sparky i have changed fiddle further as you specified Check it nw.

Comment: Hi Anthony , i have updated. I am not sure whether it is closing as in opened order.

Comment: So very close! http://jsfiddle.net/waJzP/55/ ---- can you make it so that stage 3 and stage 2 close BEFORE the photos opens so they do not open and close at the same time?

Comment: I have modified as stage2 and stage3 closing before photo opens but i am not aware of what you mean by  "so they do not open and close at the same time? " check  for updated fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/waJzP/74/ It is very close Sridhar - The problem is that if you open stage 1, stage 2, close - then reopen stage 1, stage 2 - it actually opens stage 2 and stage 3 at the same time. Also, the delays are not working properly - there should be no delay on the photo close when nothing else is open, only a delay when stage 1 or stage 2 is open